# IBM Worklight - Push Notification for IBM appcenter client (apk) Not delivering

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am trying to get the push notification on android appcenter client(apk) for every update from app-center console, I have configured everything as per docs (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc%2Fappcenter%2Ft_ac_gcm_connect.html). When i see the logs there is no any error but it says

[4/23/14 1:43:50:447 PDT] 0000002e AppCenterServletContextListener                              I The list of messages to be pushed has been cleaned up.

for every 10 second. but am not getting any notification on my device.
my liberty server.xml configs are
jndiName="ibm.appcenter.gcm.signature.googleapikey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
jndiName="ibm.appcenter.push.schedule.period.amount" value="10"
jndiName="ibm.appcenter.push.schedule.period.unit" value="seconds"

please tell me where is the mistake.

Comment: Are you using a real device or a simulator. Please provide more detail. Also I wouldn't recommend including your GCM API key in the post above.

Comment: Did you see the message "The list of messages to be pushed has been cleaned up" only once or each 10 seconds? Also take a look to the database table PUSH_BATCH to check if there are entries.

Comment: Hi, Yes I'm using real device to test and there is no any entries in PUSH_BATCH table of appcenter, but I'm getting the push notification token entry(PUSH_ID) in DEVICE table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "The list of messages to be pushed has been cleaned up" occurs when the system sends out the push notifications. That is: when an app is updated, the corresponding push notification is first queued. Then, every X seconds/minutes/hours, the queue is cleaned and all pending push notifications are sent. At that time point, you see the message "The list of messages to be pushed has been cleaned up" in the log. Hence, this log message is normal.

Possible reasons that the push notification does not reach an Android device:

- Most common: No google account is set on the device. See under Settings | Accounts whether you have a google account for the device. I think when you log in to Google Play or to Google Mail on the device, it automatically registers your device with your google account.
- The Application Center Client was not rebuild properly after changing IBMAppCenter/apps/AppCenter/common/js/appcenter/config.json. It is not enough to set up the server, you also need to rebuild the client. The APK file that is distributed within the Worklight installation is not build for push notifications.
- On some phones available in China, push notifications are disabled (probably for legal/license reasons)
- The push service account is not properly set up. See http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html